# Hadoop latest version in binary?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

when I was about to download the [latest stable version](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/apache/hadoop/common/stable/) of hadoop as of today (06/27/2014),
I find that there is no `bin.tar.gz` available. I see the following. I am not sure which one I should download.

```
hadoop-2.2.0-src.tar.gz     07-Oct-2013 02:46   19M  
hadoop-2.2.0-src.tar.gz.mds 07-Oct-2013 02:46  1.1K  
hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz         07-Oct-2013 02:46  104M  
hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz.mds     07-Oct-2013 02:47  958
```

First of all, what is the difference between all the files above. It seems `src.tar.gz` is only `19M` but `tar.gz is 104M`. which is the preferable one to work with? Previously I used the `bin.tar.gz` for `1.2.2` as follows. but that is not available with `2.2.0` version. why is that?

for 1.2.X I used `bin.tar.gz`

```
hadoop-1.2.1-bin.tar.gz       22-Jul-2013 18:27   36M
```

Comment: Why not compile it yourself?

Comment: any particular reason why it isn't provided and what is difference the between `src.tar.gz` and `tar.gz`. The file sizes are significantly different..

Comment: There could be many reasons why it wasn't provided yet, but one thing I mainly could think of is that not all systems would be generically compatible with it. Some older versions of libraries that had supported it may also be broken now.

Comment: and whats the difference between `src.tar.gz` and `tar.gz`. which one to use?

Comment: Sorry for not noticing it quick. That `tar.gz` might actually be the bin package already. Why not try to examine the files within it?

Comment: @konsolebox but tar.gz is bigger in size than src.tar.gz. `bin` files cannot be larger than `src` I suppose?

Comment: Not always true. And it wouldn't hurt to examine those files. Are you cautious about the bandwidth you'd use for downloading?

Comment: @brainstorm Hadoop binary archives can include dependency binaries.  The `tar.gz` is most certainly the binaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Hadoop for all of it's application like HDFS, MapReduce and so you have to download `hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz`.

1.`hadoop-2.2.0-src.tar.gz` - Source code of Hadoop

2.`hadoop-2.2.0-src.tar.gz.mds` - Source code tar.gz file's checksum

3.`hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz` - Hadoop for use (Application)

4.`hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz.mds` - Checksum for Hadoop tar.gz file